# Getting undefined for this callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

prepOutput() is a simple function that takes an average and returns the callback output(), but I am getting an undefined error at "return callback(out)". Why is the callback not working?

```
    function finish() {
        isRunning = false;
        prepOutput(avgSpeed(),output());

    }

    function avgSpeed() {
        var avg = (totReactt/numClick);
        return avg.toFixed(2);
    }

    function prepOutput(avgS, callback){
        var out = "Your averege speed is " + avgS;

        return callback(out);

    }

    function output(x) {
        alert("Thank you for playing! " + x);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a function reference as the value for callback, instead you are invoking `output` and is passing the value returned from it(`undefined` as there is no value returned) as the value for `callback` argument to `prepOutput`

```
prepOutput(avgSpeed(), output);
```

Problem: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q9nwq8fg/2/) - `output` is called before `prepOutput` 
Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q9nwq8fg/)